# Dolphin is always "fullscreen"

Tags: dolphin

Some days ago Dolphin appeared to be fullscreen without an option to exit, and without the close, minimize buttons in the top right corner.

[image]

Tried to reinstall, did not help.
Is there anything else that can be done?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Kubuntu doesn't use `Alt`+`Space` by default. It uses `Alt`+`F3`. The resize option is then under `More Actions`.

Comment: Think it's solved. When i switched to i3 i've left dolphin fullscreen, so needed to login to i3, exit fullscreen and login to other wm.